# SSRS Report with Business days as Expression

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with the following header,

```
Date    28-Mar  27-Mar  25-Mar  24-Mar  23-Mar  22-Mar  21-Mar  20-Mar
Day     Fri     Thu     Wed     Tue     Mon     Sun     Sat     Fri
Pending 1       2       3       4       5       5       5       6
```

I able to generate Date and Day rows using expression with current date.

`(e.g. = Left(WeekDayName(WeekDay(DateAdd("d",-1,Now()))),3))`

But Pending Days row should display age in days with same age number for Mon, Sun and Sat since Sun and Sat are off days.

Is it possible to generate with expression?

Answer (score 0):

Got it Guys,
We just need to make sum of no of 'mon', 'tus'..'fir' in the date range.

```
=DATEDIFF("ww",DateAdd("d",-1,Now()),Now(), vbMonday)
+ 
DATEDIFF("ww",DateAdd("d",-1,Now()),Now(), vbTuesday)
```

etc.

:)